# Azure, login to separate accounts with one email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm a developer that has an Azure account for my own dev stuff.  I log into my dev account using me@hotmail.com.

Next, I set up a client with their own Azure account, then invited myself via me@hotmail.com and set myself as a co-administrator for the client's subscription.  When I subsequently log into Azure using me@hotmail.com, I only see my own subscriptions/resources, etc.

Is there a way that I can log into Azure, using me@hotmail.com, and have access to both my dev stuff as well as my client's subscription from within the portal (specifically portal.azure.com).

Not sure if this is supported or if I'm doing something wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only view subscriptions for a single directory at a time.

If you click your name in the top right corner of the portal you can select which directory you want to work from.

There is a suggestion on the Azure feedback site to add the ability to view subscriptions from all directories: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/4761959-manage-subscriptions-across-all-available-director